# How do I know camera preview has started and I am ready to take a picture?

Tags: android, camera

I am making an application that will shoot a photo automatically from the back camera every 10 seconds. But the problem is that I am not able to detect whether the preview has started or not. I want to take a picture as soon as a camera preview is available. Anyone knows a method which triggers when a camera preview is ready ?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189885/is-there-any-way-to-listen-for-when-the-camera-has-loaded-in-cwac-camera